# Spring RMI Remoting Annotation Configuration

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I have been looking for some time for this and I can't seem to find the answer. I am using Spring RMI remoting and I would like to use annotation configuration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I remember there is no standard annotation based RMI support from spring. I came across [this link](http://rpgkan.blogspot.in/2010/05/rmi-remote-server-on-spring-framework.html) (*its in Thai*) which briefs about creating a **custom annotation** which can be use within spring container environment.

Comment: A custom annotation in this link https://github.com/earldouglas/barebones-spring-mvc/tree/master/reference/spring-remoting-annotation

Comment: Neither the link in this post, nor the comment work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As @Santosh answered, there isn't standard annotation for RMI support. But you can use standard bean annotation to register RMI beans.

Do this on service side (parameter barService is implementation of service injected by Spring -> so there needs to be such bean already registered):

```
@Bean
public RmiServiceExporter registerService(BarService barService) {
    RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
    rmiServiceExporter.setServiceName("BarService");
    rmiServiceExporter.setService(barService);
    rmiServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(BarService.class);
    rmiServiceExporter.setRegistryPort(5000);

    return rmiServiceExporter;
}
```

Client side:

```
@Bean
public BarService createBarServiceLink() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:5000/BarService");
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(BarService.class);
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (BarService) rmiProxyFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: I was doing exactly as you did, but I'm getting an 
`EOFException: The client aborted the connection`, I'm running the Spring Context in a Web Container (Tomcat). Did you get such a problem ?

Comment: I am trying to convert my application from an xml and properties file based configuration to an annotation and java based configuration using Spring and Dropwizard. I have tried using your client side code in my application but it gives a classcast exception. I cannot make changes on the service side as it is a different system and can only make changes at client side. Is this doable?How can I do this without touching the service side(other systems code).