# Spring RMI using annotations, Modifications possible only on client side

Tags: spring, annotations, rmi

I am trying to convert my application from an xml and properties file based configuration to an annotation and java based configuration using Spring and Dropwizard. I have tried using the following client side code referring [Spring RMI Remoting Annotation Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138207/spring-rmi-remoting-annotation-configuration) in my application but it gives a classcast exception.

```
@Bean
public BarService createBarServiceLink() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:5000/BarService");
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(BarService.class);
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (BarService) rmiProxyFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

The older application has BarService class not extending any other class and the entire configuration is done in xmls but it still works.

I cannot make changes on the service side as it is a different system and can only make changes at client side. 
Is this doable? How can I do this without touching the service side(other systems code).

Answer (score 1):

See in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-remoting-rmi that your return must be:

```
@Bean
public RmiProxyFactoryBean createBarServiceLink() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:5000/BarService");
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(BarService.class);
    rmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rmiProxyFactoryBean;
}
```

On getBean() the spring known as call BarService. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws BookingException {
    BarService service = SpringApplication
      .run(RmiClient.class, args).getBean(BarService.class);
    // use service
}
```

In this way you don't change in server or client side.